TypeScript: How to validate input fields with form checkboxes
I have a form with several checkboxes and corresponding input fields.
<div class="group-wrap input-element" id="gr_">
  <div class="label-bar">
    <label>
      <div class="custom-control form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="1" type="checkbox" id="Gleitzeitmaxstundenenable" name="Gleitzeitmaxstundenenable" onmouseup="{setActFeld(this.id);}" onfocus="{ setActFeld(this.id);}" onclick="{setConfirmedChange(this.id, &quot;false&quot;) ; initCheckBox(this.id);transaktionObj.inputEnable(this.checked,&quot;Gleitzeitmaxstunden&quot;);}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Gleitzeitmaxstundenenable">Gleitzeit max.</label>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input placeholder="Gleitzeitmaxstunden" name="Gleitzeitmaxstunden" class="form-control text-truncate input-sm zeit-raum withSign numValPicker timecount disabled" data-syntax="-NNN:NN" value="" data-prefix="true" id="Gleitzeitmaxstunden" maxlength="7" type="text" onmousedown="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, false));}}" onkeyup="{  if(checkPicker(this.id)){ return false;} else{return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, true));}}" onfocus="{ setActFeld(this.id);}" onkeydown="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, false));}}" onmouseup="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, false));}}" onkeypress="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, false));}}" onchange="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){setConfirmedChange(this.id, &quot;false&quot;); return false;}else{setConfirmedChange(this.id, &quot;false&quot;);}}" onblur="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{scanValueAufHtml(this.id);convertZeitGt23(this.id,this.value,3,999);}}" onclick="{ if(checkPickerVoll(this.id)){ return false;}else{openNumpadV3(&quot;toggle§Gleitzeitmaxstunden&quot;, event);return (updateZeitMitSign(this,4, false));}}"
  ></div>
</div>

When a checkbox is checked and the user enters a value in the corresponding input field then the TS method should return true.
        let fehler = false;
        $JQ("input.form-check-input").each(function(ind: number, checkBox: Element){
            const checkbox = $JQ(checkBox);
            const inputId = checkbox.attr("id").replace("enable", "");
            
            if($JQ(`#${inputId}`).val() !== ""){
                fehler = true;
            }
        });
       
        return fehler;

But $JQ(#${inputId}).val() !== "" always gives true. Kindly, help me.

Just to understand the use case. You would like to validate only the form fields/inputs where the checkbox is checked? And the form will only submit if the fields er valid?

I want it to return true only if the checkbox is checked and input field has some value and it's not empty.

When will the test hapoen? And what will you use the return value for? Let's say you have 5 true and 1 false, or all 6 are true -- then what?

I want to return true if any one of the checkboxes (checked) with its input field is not empty.

If a checkbox is changed set the required property on the input element to true or false.
The form will only submit if all required form fields are valid -- in this example -- has any value. You can require something more specific by using attributes like pattern, minlength or maxlength for text input (<input type="text">).


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let elm = e.target;
  
  switch(elm.type){
    case 'checkbox':
      form[elm.dataset.name].required = elm.checked;
      break;
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitting');
});
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
<form name="form01">
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="text01"></label>
    <label>Text 01: <input type="text" name="text01"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="text02"></label>
    <label>Text 02: <input type="text" name="text02"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-name="text03"></label>
    <label>Text 03: <input type="text" name="text03"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




in js you should check the checked attribute rather than value for checkbox inputs
So would be
document.getElementById(inputId).checked;

in jquery think would be like
$(`#${inputId}`).is(":checked");

